# How to export (to word or ppt) editable graph generated in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, save, edit

**I want to save the generated graph (by ggplot2 or any other package) into editable formate inside the word or ppt. How to do this in R?
I have used**

```
install.packages("ReporteRs")
install.packages("export")
```

but displaying same message i.e.

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ACER/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ReporteRs’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)


Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ACER/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘export’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

**So is there any updated/smoothly working package?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ReporteRs` package has been renamed `officer`, per the [ReporteRs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ReporteRs/versions/0.8.10) documentation.

To install...

```
install.packages("officer")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the eoffice package:

```
install.packages("eoffice")
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, color = factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
topptx(filename = file.path(tempdir(), "mtcars.pptx"))
## or todocx(filename = "mtcars.docx")
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, color = factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
topptx(p, filename = file.path(tempdir(), "mtcars.pptx"), width = 6, height = 4)
```